# Tomcat welcome-file-list https redirect

Tags: tomcat, servlets, https

My Tomcat server is very standard, with a default  element that successfully redirects pages like http://website.com/folder to http://website.com/folder/index.cfm

However, it also redirects **https**://website.com/folder to http://website.com/folder/index.cfm

How do I make it respect the protocol / port when redirecting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790141/security-constraint-configuration-inside-web-xml-for-tomcat

Comment: @coding_idiot I don't think it's a duplicate of that question. To be clear, HTTPS works fine for me, it's only "welcome" page redirects that force HTTPS queries to become HTTP. I assume this comes from the <welcome-file-list> servlet, but that's just a guess.

Comment: well in that case, you have to tell more about the default element you're using for redirection.