# Web Application under Tomcat with SSL

Tags: tomcat, ssl, https, http-status-code-401

I wanted to secure an application I developed recently, and I following mkyong's tutorial.

It worked only for tomcat manager's pages.

Indeed, I use the  `<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>` with `<auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>`.

At the beginning, I wasn't sure about mkyong's certificate, so I followed instructions in [maximporges](http://www.maximporges.com/2009/11/18/configuring-tomcat-ssl-clientserver-authentication/).

I keep getting error code 401.

When I change ***auth-method*** from CLIENT-CERT to BASIC, I am prompted to enter login and password, I enter a user's credentials that exists in **tomcat-users.xml**, and it works.

I tried to add a user in **tomcat-users.xml** like `<user username="CN=xxxx xxx xxx, O=knmi, O=users, O=dutchgrid" password="null" roles="abc" />` I duplicate the exact same information entered previously for the certificate, but doesn't work.

I think the server can't find the client's certificate

Note: I had to change `protocol="HTTP/1.1"` to `protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"` in **server.xml** to avoid getting `ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT`.

Comment: This question is not well explained. Do you want to stablish a secure web channel ssl/tls(contento encrypted)? Or also identfy clients with certificate?

Comment: I want to establish a secure connection (sorry for the confusion).

Comment: Therefore you do not need a client certificate. This is simple http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-configure-tomcat-to-support-ssl-or-https/ If you want a 'green bar' I suggest buy an SSL certificate instead of generating one

Comment: It won't work with <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee> in web.xml

Comment: It is not necessary. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790141/is-security-constraint-configuration-for-tomcat-mandatory

Comment: Thanks. It works. But how to force HTTPS?

Comment: Disable the http connector, usually on port 8080. Then, only the https connector will be reachable

Answer (score 1):

[Response from comments]

To stablish a secure connection you do not need a client certificate. Here you are a simple tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-configure-tomcat-to-support-ssl-or-https/

If you want a 'green bar' I suggest buy an SSL certificate instead of generating one

Tomcat tag in web.xml is not needed. See [Is security-constraint configuration for Tomcat mandatory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790141/is-security-constraint-configuration-for-tomcat-mandatory)

```
<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
```

To force HTTPS disable the http connector, usually on port 8080. Then, only the https connector will be reachable