# Can not read JSESSIONID cookie after setting cookie-config to httpOnly and secure in web.xml

Tags: java, tomcat, cookies, session-cookies, tomcat8.5

I have added the following configuration in my webapp application web.xml

```
  <session-config>
    <cookie-config>
      <path>/</path>
      <http-only>true</http-only>
      <secure>true</secure>
    </cookie-config>
 </session-config>
```

When I start my application, I send an http request to set this cookie and I can see it in the http response with path /, Secure and httpOnly.

However, I can't see this cookie being sent inside the following http requests and hence, if I do request.getSession().getId() for the following requests, I get an empty string.

I tried adding the following to my tomcat 8.5 context and also the WAR context

```
<Context sessionCookiePath="/">
```

but it did not fix the issue.

Does that mean that the JSESSIONID cookie is not being secure and hence ignored to be sent within the requests?

Comment: Do you access your app via `https`?

Comment: Hi, no, http. localhost to be specific.

I also note that for each request, there is a new session created. 

I have a filter in the middleware and I can see that each request has a different sessionId when I set the configuration in web.xml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per your comment you are setting the session cookie `secure` attribute to `true`, using a `http` connection for transport.

While the `http` protocol in use does not guarantee confidential transport, you correctly indicate that the session is sensitive information by activating the `secure` attribute. Therefore the browser denies to send this information back to the server via unsecure plain text `http` transport.

Read this Q/A for additional details: [How does cookie “Secure” flag work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729749/how-does-cookie-secure-flag-work)

As the JSESSIONID is never sent back to the server, each request will end up creating a new session which is never used for subsequent requests.

The solution is to either disable the `secure` attribute, or prefarably [configure and use a `https` connector in tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Configuration).

You should also [configure your app to accept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790141/is-security-constraint-configuration-for-tomcat-mandatory) `https` connections only and redirect `http` to `https`.

Comment: That was really helpful :) Thanks a lot.